# md-button disappears when adding an href

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and i'm getting some troubles. Usually I find a way to fix it but not this time.

So the problem is I want to use an md-button as a link to another page. But, when I add an href, the button disappears from the page.
Here is my code:

home.html

```
    <body ng-app="friend-s-app">
    <div ng-controller="friendsappController">
        <md-toolbar>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

        <md-button href="/home.html" >
            Home
        </md-button>

    </div>
</md-toolbar>
</div>

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

app.js in case you want it :

```
    (function(angular, undefined){
        "use strict";

        angular
            .module('friend-s-app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ng'])
            .controller('friendsappController', inscriptionEditor)
            .controller('InscriptionSheet', InscriptionSheet);

function inscriptionEditor($scope, $mdDialog) {
    var alert;

    $scope.myPathVariable = 'path/to/somewhere';
    $scope.showInscription = showInscriptionSheet;
    $scope.showSignIn = showSignIn;
    function showInscriptionSheet($event) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            targetEvent: $event,
            template:
            '<md-dialog layout="column">' +
                '<md-content>' +
                    '<form style="padding: 20px;">' +
                        '<div layout="row">' +
                            '<md-input-container>' +
                                '<label>First name</label>' +
                                '<input ng-model="user.firstName" required/>' +
                                '<div ng-messages="userForm.firstName.$error" ng-show="userForm.firstName.$dirty">' +
                                    '<div ng-message="required">This is required!</div> '+
                                '</div>' +
                            '</md-input-container>' +
                            '<md-input-container>' +
                                '<label>Last name</label>' +
                                '<input ng-model="user.lastName" required/>' +
                                '<div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-show="userForm.lastName.$dirty">' +
                                    '<div ng-message="required">This is required!</div> '+
                                '</div>' +
                            '</md-input-container>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<md-input-container style="width: 50%">' +
                            '<label>Nickname</label>' +
                            '<input ng-model="user.nickname" required minlength="5" maxlength="15"/>' +
                        '</md-input-container>' +
                        '<div layout="row">' +
                            '<md-input-container>' +
                                '<label>Password</label>' +
                                '<input ng-model="user.password" type="password" required minlength="5" maxlength="15"/>' +
                            '</md-input-container>' +
                            '<md-input-container>' +
                                '<label>Repeat password</label>' +
                                '<input ng-model="user.repassword" type="password" required minlength="5" maxlength="15"/>' +
                            '</md-input-container>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<md-input-container>' +
                            '<label>E-mail</label>' +
                            '<input ng-model="user.email" required/>' +
                        '</md-input-container>'+
                        '<div layout="row">'+
                            '<md-button ng-Click="closeDialog()" style="width:50%">' +
                                'Cancel' +
                            '</md-button>' +
                            '<md-button style="width: 50%">' +
                                'Validate' +
                            '</md-button>' +
                        '</div>'+
                    '</form>'+
                '</md-content>'+
            '</md-dialog>',

            controller: 'InscriptionSheet',
            onComplete: afterShowAnimation,
            locals: { employee: $scope.userName }
        });


        function afterShowAnimation(scope, element, options) {
        }
    }
    function showSignIn($event) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            targetEvent: $event,
            template:
            '<md-dialog>' +
                '<md-content>' +
                '<md-input-container>' +
                    '<label>Nickname</label>' +
                    '<input ng-model="user.nickName" required/>' +
                    '<div ng-messages="userForm.nickName.$error" ng-show="userForm.nickName.$dirty">' +
                        '<div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</md-input-container>' +
                '<md-input-container>' +
                    '<label>Password</label>' +
                    '<input ng-model="user.password" required type="password"/>' +
                    '<div ng-messages="userForm.password.$error" ng-show="userForm.password.$dirty">' +
                        '<div ng-message="required">This is required!</div> '+
                    '</div>' +
                '</md-input-container> ' +
                '<div layout="row">'+
                    "<md-button ng-Click=\"closeDialog()\" style=\"width: 50%\" >" +
                        'Cancel' +
                    '</md-button>' +
                    '<md-button style="width: 50%" href="home.html">' +
                        'Validate' +
                    '</md-button>' +
                '</div>'+
                '</md-content>' +
            '</md-dialog>',

            controller: 'InscriptionSheet',
            onComplete: afterShowAnimation,
            locals: { employee: $scope.userName }
        });

        function afterShowAnimation(scope, element, options) {
        }
    }
}

function InscriptionSheet($scope, $mdDialog, employee) {
    $scope.employee = employee;

    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };
}

    })(angular);
```

And there are the results : 
Without the href :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKRKS.png

With it :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4JqC.png

thanks for helping me.

Comment: `href` on button will never work, it only has click event

Comment: `href` is supported by `md-button`. Attaching an `href` attribute to an `md-button` just turns it into an `a` tag rather than a `button`.

Comment: A link to a plunkr/codepen/jsbin would be super helpful!

Comment: Okay thank you, but when I change href to ng-href with a value in scope, the same issue occurs. Do you know a way to fix it ? Or may I use an ng-click with a specified action in my JS file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just experienced a similar issue. Note when you switch from an ng-click to an ng-href it will inject an anchor tag instead of a button. To maintain the same visual characteristics I needed to apply an `display: inline-block;` to the .md-button class (which gets added to the aforementioned anchor tag) in my CSS. This may be the cause of it disappearing on your side.

Let me know if that makes sense or requires any further elaboration.